# codeigniter input date field should not accept previous days

Tags: php, html

I want my input date field to only accept today's date moving forward. I have tried the following way and I get this error:

> "Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN."

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Requested Date</label>
<input type="date" name="confirmed_date" class="form-control" id="log6" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't reproducible. `echo date('Y-m-d');` outputs something like `2021-05-13` (demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d88e68e342a70efb44eb89b6e2f1fe3e1ba2ad14 . If we put that into the `min` attribute of a date input as static text, it works exactly as expected, without errors - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yg6ws8kb/ . I can only assume that maybe your PHP code isn't being executed correctly or something. Have you checked the HTML (via the View Source or element inspector) in your browser to see what that `min` property actually contains in reality?

Comment: Also where exactly are you seeing that error? And what is the stack trace for it? Even putting the literal text `<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>` into the `min` attribute doesn't produce that error (in the Console or anywhere else) - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yg6ws8kb/1/ (it fails to restrict the date, as of course you'd imagine, but there isn't an error message - it simply ignores the invalid value). I can only assume that message is generated by some other JavaScript (or even PHP) which you haven't shown us.

Comment: the error comes just below the input field

Comment: Ok well it must be generated by some other validation code. But did you do what I suggested and check the exact contents of the HTML? Does it show a date in the `min` attribute?

Comment: on page source the min attribute passes date as such: min="2021-05-13"

Comment: Ok well that's as expected then. The date selector should work - days before today will be greyed out.

Comment: any idea on how can i solve this issue? is there something im missing?

Comment: As I mentioned already, your validation error must be generated by some other code which you haven't shown in your question, and is presumably is making a mistake and not reading the `min` value correctly (or some related mistake). Find that code, and debug it. Post it in your question if you need help with fixing it.

Comment: found out my jquery was outdated..the code works fine now Thanks